# why doesnt this type wildcard work?

Tags: java, generics

```
interface A {
    String n();
}
class B implements A {
    @Override
    public String n() { return "asdf"; }
}
interface C<T extends A> {
    T m(T t);
}
class D implements C<B> {
    @Override
    public B m(B b) {
        return b;
    }
}

Class<C<? extends A>> x = D.class;
```

there is an error on the last line

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<D> to Class<C<? extends A>>
```

this looks perfectly fine to me, but maybe i am missing some subtlety on how type wildcards work. Is there a way i can change the type on the last line? i need this reference because i plan on doing this later:

```
B b = new B();
A y = x.newInstance().m(b);
```

this also has an error

```
The method m(capture#1-of ? extends A) in the type C<capture#1-of ? extends A> is not applicable for the arguments (B)
```

however, if i use it without the wildcards and capture, it works fine:

```
A z = D.class.newInstance().m(b);
```

unfortunately im kinda stuck with this for now, any help would be appreciated.

edit: removed `this.` references

**edit**: changed x to be

```
Class<? extends C<? extends A>> x = D.class;
```

and it works. however still getting errors on `x.newInstance().m(b)`

```
The method m(capture#2-of ? extends A) in the type Test.C<capture#2-of ? extends A> is not applicable for the arguments (B)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, focusing just on the last part:

> however still getting errors on x.newInstance().m(b)
>
> ```
> The method m(capture#2-of ? extends A) in the type
> Test.C<capture#2-of ? extends A is not applicable for the arguments (B)
> ```

Indeed - and that makes perfect sense. Because nothing in your code indicates that you've actually got a `C<B>`. All the compiler knows is that `newInstance` has returned an instance of *some* type which implements `C<X>` for *some* type `X` which implements `A`. How would it know that that's `B`?

If you want to call `m(b)`, you'll need a `C<B>`, which means that your declaration would need to be

```
Class<? extends C<B>> x = D.class;
```

At that point, the method invocation compiles cleanly. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, or whether this will be good enough for you - but hopefully it explains why you're getting the error you're getting...

Comment: doesnt `B implement A` though? i have a `B` in this example, but i want the library work with `A`'s. The library is a preference or configuration library. A is HasPreferences, and C is the serializeable Preference class. so there will be subtypes of each, with subclasses of C<A> meaning C is the preference object for A.

Comment: C will get A's to grab configuration info out of. and will also apply the configuration on them. there can be multiple C's for an A. (which is why i templatized it that way, rather than the other way around)

Comment: @aepurniet: `B` implements `A`, but the parameter to `C.m` isn't of type `A` - it's of type `T`. `D` can rely on getting an instance of `B`, not of some other implementation of `A`. That's why it's causing a problem. There's nothing in the declaration of `Class<? extends C<? extends A>>` which mentions `B`...

Comment: i agree, but changing everything to B is not an option, since this library needs to deal with the interface A, not the concrete class B that it knows nothing about. there will be many classes that extend A.

Comment: B implements A, and T is <T extents A>. which should work in my mind. it does work when generics are not nested.

Comment: @aepurniet: It's important that you understand *why* it doesn't work. Imagine if the code you'd written compiled - that means it would have to work when you passed some *other* implementation of `A` to `newInstance().m(...)`. But `D` *only* works with `B`. Do you see the problem now? If you changed `C.m()` so that its parameter type was just `A`, that would be fine - but then you'd need to change `D.m()` to work with any implementation, not just `B`.

Comment: `x.newInstance()` should return a `C<? extends A>`. think im a little lost on the capture rules. i see what your saying about when its compiled though. the method in D only exists for B. (which is desired behavior). however, how do i take this template and apply it to all other classes that may arise?

Comment: @aepurniet: Yes, `x.newInstance()` returns a `C<? extends A>` - which means that *all* the compiler knows about the `T` there is that it's *something* which extends `A`. That doesn't mean you can use *any* `A` as the argument. It's hard to know exactly what your situation is, but I strongly suspect you're not going to be able to express this relationship in a type-safe way at this point.

Comment: @skeet thats what i was missing! `? extends A` does not mean anything that extends A, its something that extends A. im using type unsafety now, nut will wiggle with it some more.

Answer (score 0):

its type unsafe (i think, have those warnings turned off to avoid annotation pollution)

```
    Class<? extends C> x = D.class;
    B b = new B();
    A y = x.newInstance().m(b);
    A z = D.class.newInstance().m(b);
```

but it works.